# Mock function of class methods argument in Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I have this Jest test within a Nest application:

```
import {Test, TestingModule} from '@nestjs/testing';
import {DefaultGateway} from './default.gateway';
import {Sockt} from '../data.module';

describe('DefaultGateway', () => {
    let gateway: DefaultGateway;
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                DefaultGateway],
        }).compile();
        
        gateway = module.get<DefaultGateway>(DefaultGateway);
    });
    
    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(gateway).toBeDefined();
    });
    
    it('should ...', async () => {
        await gateway.handleConnection({compress: jest.fn(), disconnect: jest.fn(), handshake: {query: {jwt: '12sdf908'}}} as unknown as Sockt);
        //expect(compress).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true); what to write here??
    });
});
```

And this DefaultGateway:

```
import {Sockt} from "../data.module";
import {OnGatewayConnection, WebSocketGateway} from '@nestjs/websockets';

@WebSocketGateway({
    transports: ['websocket']
})
export class DefaultGateway implements OnGatewayConnection {
    
    public handleConnection(socket: Sockt): any {
        
        if (socket.handshake.query.jwt
            || (socket.handshake.query.uuid
                && socket.handshake.query.password)) {
            
            socket.compress(true);
            
        } else {
            
            socket.disconnect(true);
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

I want to expect that `socket.compress()` and `socket.disconnect()` will be called with true.
But because `compress` and `disconnect` are functions passed as params, I have no clue how to mock it. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by passing a mock function:

```
it('should call compress', async () => {
    
    const mockImplementation = () => {};
    const mockCompress = jest.fn(mockImplementation);
    
    await gateway.handleConnection({compress: mockCompress, disconnect: jest.fn(), handshake: {query: {jwt: '12sdf908'}}} as unknown as Sockt);

    expect(mockCompress).toHaveBeenCalledWith(true);
});
```